# Solve the following Diffrential Equation $(x+y+1)dx+(2x+2y-1)dy=0$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I want to seperate variables in the following equation and need some advice:
$$(x+y+1)dx+(2x+2y-1)dy=0$$
what I tried to do so far is:
$$ydx+(x+1)dx+(2y-1)dy+2xdy=0$$
now how I should I continue? thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Hint:**

Setting $$(x+y+1)=u\longrightarrow 2x+2y-1=2u-3,~~~dx+dy=du$$ makes your ODE separable.

Comment: I didnt understand $2dx+2dy=du$ how you get to this equation? its not suppose to be $2du$?

Comment: It should be $2\,dx+2\,dy=2\,du$, or more simply $\,dx+\,dy=\,du$.

Comment: @OfirAttia: Ohh yes. Honestly I was having my meal. :)

Comment: What I get at the end is: $$udu+(2u-3)du=0$$ this is the right equation?

Comment: @OfirAttia: In fact, you have $$(3-u)dx+(2u-3)du=0$$

Comment: I missed something, why its $3-u$ and why there is $dx$?

Comment: @OfirAttia: $udx+(2u-3)(du-dx)=0\to dx(u-2u+3)dx+(2u-3)du=0$

Comment: Short and sweet. +1 for my friend!

Comment: @BabakS.: Needs another TU, very nice approach +1